# Will querying a database each second affect system performance

Tags: sql, database, performance, websocket

I have an api exposing a websocket connection and to keep the connection alive my reactjs frontend echoes in the websocket connection each second. Whenever the server receives the message, a database query (a SELECT) is done. So I'm querying the database each second by the way. Will it kill the system overtime ? Is it a poor practice to query a database as frequently as that ? Any explanation would help me improve the code. My system will go production in a few and I'd like not to encounter any silly problem

Answer (score 1):

According to your words, a query is executed every second, and by doing this, you will have problems with the server resources

In my opinion, you can have two different solutions

1- Manage the number of requests from the database using the design pattern and data caching

2- Change your websocket structure and in case of an event or data changes, take the data from the bank and send it to the user.

Comment: Thank you @AryanHasanzadeh for your answer. I'll consider investigating the second solution